# What is "impart" meaning in some Chinese internet language?

Tags: internet-slang

In Chinese internet languages, some English words appears. But the meaning is totally different from the original English meaning, just like the following

- 你不准参加impart
- 开impart怎么不带我啊

I wonder what is "impart" meaning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposedly the transition went like this:

- impart sounds like 银趴
- 银趴 is a substitute for 淫趴 -or- an *orgy*
- now impart is used more widely to mean anything good that you haven't been invited to

Seems like it might have come from Thor: Love and Thunder

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> impart，或者impact，是淫趴的谐音，简中互联网为了应对网络社区或者论坛不被识别删除故意打成银趴。淫趴原本是国外一种私人举办的派对Home Party，可能会比较性自由和开放，然而国内这个梗流行起来，首先是因为2022年初网络开放了ip显示，不少网民发现很多人的ip是在国外，譬如美国、北欧等，加上整年舆情都非常激烈，润成为了一种强烈的想法，而且大部分人是没有条件润的，于是只能骗已经润的人回来，于是就会在国外ip的网友下面留言，村里开银趴了，快回来吧，村里开银趴发金条了，快回来吧，实际上是对成功润到国外的一种羡慕；其次银趴怎么突然成了网络语境中美好奢靡的代名词呢，最早是因为国内有过海天盛筵这种真银趴的事件报道过，于是上层有钱人荒淫奢靡成了一种自由和享受的调侃，然后近些年被广泛使用是出自电影《雷神4》索尔被扒的片段，男主索尔(托尔)因为和宙斯意见不合，索尔的衣服被宙斯扒光了，并且说了一句话：You can not come to orgy，国内翻译为：你不准参加银趴，可以说非常地信达雅了，由此，银趴正式成了一种戏谑荒诞的网络意象，也衍生了一些表情包，比如哆啦A梦的开银趴不叫我是吧。

Quoted from [鲸吼](https://www.jinghooo.com/definition/4549), which explained pretty clearly in Chinese. Please feel free to post a better answer, written in English, to “trump” this one.

<sup>*This answer was originally intended to be sent as a link in question comments, but unfortunately I do not have the privilege to post comments, so have to send as this answer.*</sup>